# How can I push music to my Android device with Google Play Music?

Tags: google-play-music

I want to **push** music to my Android device running Google Music. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple but not obvious at first.

1. Create a Playlist (e.g. 'Offline')
2. Open Google Play Music on your Android device and select the playlist
3. Check 'Keep on device' for the playlist
4. Go to http://music.google.com and add tracks to this playlist
5. You device will download the tracks, *even if you add them with the web interface*

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively open up the Play Music app on your phone.
Using the menu navigate to My Library.
Choose the Album view.
under the album picture is the 3 dots, press on them to bring up menu options, one of which is Keep on Device. Press that to download the music to your phone.

You can specify phone or SD Card (if available) by going into the Play Music settings option and changing the Storage Location under the Downloading options.